In certain religions like Jainism, killing, or eating of seeds or unicellular microorganisms is banned. Does slicing of sporangia kill all the spores?
In certain religions like Jainism, killing, or eating of seeds or unicellular microorganisms is banned. Does sectioning of sporangia kill all the spores? And by the way do the spores form a part of parent generation, or the offspring generation? Are the spores fully developed in the strobilus before dehiscence?

Sorry, but this question doesn’t seem relevant to this site. It’s a purely biological question about sectioning and the multiplication of spores.

Same thing even biology stack exchange website is telling me for this question.

Well, if you remove the first sentence from the body of your question, it's purely a biology question only - Does sectioning of sporangia kill all the spores? And by the way do the spores form a part of parent generation, or the offspring generation? Are the spores fully developed in the strobilus before dehiscence? You don't need to state your Jaina mata regarding ahiṁsā towards all jīvas, instead simply ask the biology question, not on this site though. You may do so on biology stack exchange.
